# gcc linking error

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to build [libvterm's](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvterm/?source=dlp) demo included in the source.

I have this folder structure:

```
- libvterm/
  ... // all sources are here
  - libvterm.so
  - vterm.h
  - demo/
    - vshell.c
```

Within the demo directory I did:

```
$ gcc -o vshell `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 ncurses` vshell.c -L.. -I.. -lvterm
```

I get lots of `undefined reference to` errors, even after definind **-I** and **-L** to point to the right directory:

```
/tmp/ccAlNYtQ.o: In function `main':
vshell.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `initscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `noecho'
vshell.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `start_color'
vshell.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `raw'
vshell.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `nodelay'
vshell.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `keypad'
vshell.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `init_pair'
vshell.c:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `waddch'
vshell.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
vshell.c:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `newwin'
vshell.c:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
vshell.c:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
vshell.c:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `wtouchln'
vshell.c:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
vshell.c:(.text+0x2be): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x2c6): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
vshell.c:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `stdscr'
vshell.c:(.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `wgetch'
vshell.c:(.text+0x308): undefined reference to `endwin'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `forkpty'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `g_free'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `has_colors'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `acs_map'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `wchgat'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `beep'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `pair_content'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `COLOR_PAIRS'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `g_realloc'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `g_malloc0'
../libvterm.so: undefined reference to `wmove'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reordering your link command...

```
gcc -o vshell vshell.c -L.. -I.. -lvterm `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 ncurses`
```

At some point, the gnu linker changed to require the object first and the libraries last/later.

Comment: gcc is a compiler, not a linker, the GNU linker is not part of gcc, and it's always been documented that order matters, people just got away with doing it wrong previously

Comment: @JonathanWakely: changed gcc to gnu, that was a misstype; as to documentation, it doesn't matter what is written, just what happens. At some point it didn't matter and now it does. I've seen a small flood of these questions on SO because of it.